creating a multi-index column from an existing dataframe
I have data that is coming to me as it appears in a spreadsheet.
When it arrives it looks like this:
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
data1 = [['symbol',    'appl',  'goog',  None,     'msft',  None,   None,    None],
         ['date'  ,    'close', 'close', 'volume', 'close', 'open', 'high', 'low'],
         ['1999-01-10', 100,     101,    10000,     102,    102,    104,     105],
         ['1999-01-11', 200,     201,    10000,     202,    202,    204,     205]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df

this generates a table that looks like this:

I basically need to iterate over this data by splitting or grouping by symbol.
So the first dataframe would consist of only [date, close] column for appl,
The 2nd woudl be [date, close, volume] for goog
And the last would be [close, open, high, low] for msft
I figured to do this, if I can create a multi-index, and group by the symbols, I should be able to slice the dataframe correctly and iterate over it.
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df = df.ffill(axis=1)
#add first column by using first row
df.columns = df[:1].values.tolist()
df = df[1:]
df.columns = [df.columns, df[:1].values.tolist()]
#repeat for the fields row (2nd column above, now first column after above line)
#df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.columns.levels + df[:1].values.tolist())
#df.set_axis(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, df[:1].values.tolist()]), axis=1)
df

the last line is not working.  a few other things I have tried are commented out.
I am sure there is a better way to do this in any event...Please advise If you can.
Thanks

Code
I think using pd.MultiIndex.from_frame when creating a multi-index from dataframe is a way to reduce errors.
# your code
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df = df.ffill(axis=1)

# edit code
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df.iloc[:2, 1:].T, names=['symbol', 'ohlcv'])
out = (df.iloc[2:, 1:]
       .set_axis(df.iloc[2:, 0].rename('date'))
       .set_axis(idx, axis=1)
)

out
symbol      appl  goog         msft               
ohlcv      close close volume close open high  low
date                                              
1999-01-10   100   101  10000   102  102  104  105
1999-01-11   200   201  10000   202  202  204  205

If you are loading dataframe from a file, it is better to use the parameters header and index_col rather than this method

thank you. i also just figured out that this works df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.loc[0:1].values).  but in both cases, how would i get rid of the "symbol", "ohlc", and set index to "date".  trying df.set_index("date") fails after the operation.

im thinking maybe i do need symbol if i want to group by that level. but i do need to set the row index to date

@mike01010 In my code, index name is already date. I think the names of columns are symbol and ohlcv, but if you don't want them, you can modify them in the code above.

ok thx. i need to read and understand how your code works. i think you are taking the first 2 rows and making that a multiIndex separately. then you take from 2+ as the data rows, set the date as the index axis (level 0?), then set the column index (axis = 1) using idx? correct?  in the first line you exclude the first column also i see...im guessing if u dont do that, the names  would be 'symbol' and 'date'?

oh and to the comment about loading for file..unfortunately this is how the data comes as a json from a post request
